# Checking if URL contains certain components using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

How would I check if "http://site.com/index.php?page=main.php" is structured like this -> http://STRING.php?STRING=STRING.php using regular expression in Visual Basic .NET?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the path ends in php, and the query ends in php?  Have you looked at the Uri.GetComponents methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `http:\/\/.+\.php\?.+=.+\.php` to match that.  Some examples I used for testing can be found [here](http://rubular.com/r/ZNgKFyBUKa).

It breaks down into the different components you want and just stringing them together.  For matching the `STRINGS` you can use `.+` for a non greedy catch.  This will help you match the rest of the valid pieces of your regex, like the `php` handling.

- `http:\/\/` matches your `http://`
- `.+\.php` matches the `STRING` followed by `.php`
- `\?.+=` matches a `?` followed by a string `.+` and an `=`
- `.+\.php` finally finds a `STRING` followed by `.php` once more.

EDIT: Some example code generated for VB.NET that was generated from myregextester.com:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("http:\/\/.+\.php\?.+=.+\.php")
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: My VB.NET just freezes whenever I try to match that.

Comment: @user2230481 does it throw any error messages at all?  How long does it take to freeze?  How large is the input you are using this regex on?

Comment: No it does not, instantly, 9 characters

Comment: Could you write me an example code to verify that the URL has the specified compontents? Mine obviously seems to fail.

Comment: What is the string you are passing into it?

Comment: Using `http://www.myregextester.com/index.php` I passed in the regex provided, and the big long test string I used in the original answer.  I checked the box for VB.NET show code in the top right and hit submit.  That seems to work and generated the same response.  The code is too long, so I will add it in the answer.

Comment: The `whatever.com/index.php?page=main.php` example won't pass without the `http://` in the front of it.

Comment: I know, stackoverflow just has some weird formatting rules in the textarea -.- anyways, why all the matchcollection stuff, I just need to know wether the input url does match or not, a simple true/false function

Comment: `Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("REGEX GOES HERE")`
`Dim match As Match = regex.Match("STRING TO CHECK GOES HERE")`
`If match.Success Then`
`Console.WriteLine("WHATEVER YOU WANT")`
`End If`

Comment: No problem, if the answer was helpful don't forget to mark it as correct by checking the check mark next to the answer.  You can also upvote the answer if it was helpful.  That way, I would get credit for the help and time.